# What is exactly meant by "preserves the group operation"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm new to the topic and I'm reading "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" by Gallian an this is how isomorphism is defined:

"An isomorphism $\phi$ from a group $G$ to a group $\overline{G}$ is a one-to-one mapping (or function) from $G$ onto $\overline{G}$ that preserves the group operation."

What is exactly meant by "preserves the group operation"? The one of $G$?  $\overline{G}$?

Comment: As the answers show, **both** group operations on $G$ and $\overline G$ are involved. So it would be a little better to express this with the plural, "… preserves the group operation**s**". Of course, writing it out in equation format as the answers do is completely unambiguous, but linguistic shorthands are common nonetheless.

Comment: Then this "preserves" means that $ \phi  $ includes both operations on its own definition, right?

Comment: I would word that a bit differently: both operations are included in the definition of the phrase ``$\phi$ is an isomorphism'' (not in the definition of $\phi$).

Comment: @LeeMosher Good point, but also "preserves the group operations" can be confusing for some readers: a group has only one operation, unlike for instance a ring, so one could be puzzled by the use of the plural. An alternative wording without these issues is "preserves the group structure".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have two elements $g_1, g_2 \in G$, there are two ways to produce an element in $\bar{G}$:

1. use the binary operation $\ast$ of $G$ to produce the element $g_1\ast g_2$ of $G$, then apply the map $\phi$ to obtain $\phi(g_1\ast g_2) \in \bar{G}$.
2. apply the map $\phi$ to both $g_1$ and $g_2$ to obtain $\phi(g_1), \phi(g_2) \in \bar{G}$, then use the binary operation $\cdot$ of $\bar{G}$ to produce the element $\phi(g_1)\cdot\phi(g_2) \in \bar{G}$.

The map $\phi$ is said to preserve the binary operation if it doesn't matter which of the above two processes we use. That is, $\phi$ satisfies $\phi(g_1\ast g_2) = \phi(g_1)\cdot\phi(g_2)$ for every $g_1, g_2 \in G$. In some sense, $\phi$ maps 'products' in $G$ to 'products' in $\bar{G}$.

---

Here is a more abstract way of viewing the above condition using the notion of [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

For convenience, let $b : G\times G \to G$ and $\bar{b} : \bar{G}\times\bar{G} \to \bar{G}$ denote the binary operations on $G$ and $\bar{G}$ respectively. As we have a bijection $\phi : G \to \bar{G}$ we can 'pullback' the binary operation $\bar{b}$ to a binary operation $\phi^*\bar{b}$ on $G$ as follows: for $g_1, g_2 \in G$, we define

$$\phi^*\bar{b}(g_1, g_2) := \phi^{-1}(\bar{b}(\phi(g_1), \phi(g_2))).$$

Now we have two binary operations on $G$, namely $b$ and $\phi^*\bar{b}$. The condition above is equivalent to the statement that $\phi^*\bar{b} = b$ (i.e. the two binary operations are the same).

In the special case where $\bar{G} = G$, we have $\bar{b} = b$ so the condition reads $\phi^*b = b$. That is, the group operation of $G$ is preserved by (the pullback via) $\phi$.

Comment: But in which sense does $ \phi  $ "preserve" the operations? Is it because it includes both in its own definition?

Comment: @GniruT what Michael described in his answer is practically the definition of preserving an operation. Maybe you could clarify what about this still confuses you?

Comment: @DavidZ My confusion comes with the meaning of "preserve". For me it means that $\phi$ is associative, has neutral element and inverse i.e. it's still being an operation in a group. Otherwise, according to Michael "preserve the operation" has a mathematical meaning, which is what he just explained right?

Comment: @GniruT: $\phi$ is not a binary operation. It cannot be associative or have a neutral element. It is a mapping (aka function) between two different sets. For a general map $f:G\to \bar{G}$, you don't necessarily have $f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)f(g_2)$. But for a map that preserves the group operation, you do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ^^

Answer (score 3):

Let $g\cdot h$ denote the multiplication in $G$ and $\overline g*\overline h$ be multiplication in $\overline G$.  Then a homomorphism $f:G\to\overline G$ is a map such that

$$f(g\cdot h)=f(g)*f(h).$$

Answer (score 3):

It means that if $(G, \ast_{G},e_{G})$ and $(\overline{G}, \ast_{\overline{G}},e_{\overline{G}})$ are groups with their respective operation $\ast_{G}$ and $\ast_{\overline{G}}$. Then $\phi: G \to \overline{G}$ is an isomorphism if $\phi$ is *bijective* and for every $x,y \in G$:

$$\phi(x\ast_{G}y)=\phi(x)\ast_{\overline{G}}\phi(y).$$

The latter condition means that $\phi$ *preserves the group operations*.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $f(e_G)= e_{\overline G}$, and for all $x,y\in G, f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$, which together imply that $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't think the identity mapping is necessary. Indeed if $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ then we have $f(x) = f(e_G x) = f(e_G) f(x)$ and $f(x) = f(x e_G) = f(x) f(e_G)$ since this holds for all $x \in G$ and $f$ is one-to-one then it also holds for all $f(x) = y \in \overline{G}$ and hence $f(e_G)$ is the identity of $\overline{G}$.

Comment: Why do you need that $f(x) = f(e_G x) = f(e_G) f(x)$ AND $f(x) = f(x e_G) = f(x) f(e_G)$ PLUS the hypothesis of bijectivity to have $f(e_{G})=e_{\overline{G}}$? 

Take f not bijective and only 
$$f(x) = f(e_G x) = f(e_G) f(x)
\implies f(x)f(x)^{-1}=f(e_{G})f(x)f(x)^{-1}
\implies e_{\overline{G}}=f(e_{G})e_{\overline{G}}
\implies e_{\overline{G}}=f(e_{G})$$

The inverse of $f(x)$ in $\overline{G}$ exists because $\overline{G}$ is a group, so where do we need bijectivity and the second equality $f(x) = f(x e_G) = f(x) f(e_G)$?

Finally, how do we conclude that $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1}$?

Comment: True, and bijectivity not required to infer that $f$ preserves the identity element. Just what the operation or operations plural of groups are, is of course relative to the axioms used. In the most redundant case, there are three: $e$, $*$, and $^{-1}$ (constants can be taken to be 0-ary operations). The axioms are such that when defining homomorphisms, it's redundant to specify that these are all preserved. For other kinds of structures, that isn't in general true.

Comment: I see, and the inverse is preserved since

$$f(e_{G})=f(xx^{-1})=f(x)f(x^{-1})$$

now multiply left both sides by $f(x)^{-1}$ and you get $f(x)^{-1}=f(x^{-1})$.

Is this the right terminology "multiply left"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and it's the correct terminology.. I would have said "right" but didn't want to be confusing - left/right & so on :)

Comment: I was also going to add *\*pun intended\** at the end of my last sentence ;)

Comment: I for one would have laughed. And given a shorter answer ;/